# Good software for linear/integer programming

Tags: soft-question, math-software, linear-programming, integer-programming

I never did any linear/integer programming so I am wondering the following two things

- What are some efficient free linear programming solvers?
- What are some efficient commercial linear programming solvers?

It would be nice to supply a dummy usage example with each proposed answer.

Also what if wish to solve a integer programming problem? What are the answers to the above two questions in this case?

I know that integer LP is a hard problem but there are some relaxing methods that are sometimes employed in order to obtain a solution to an integer programming problem. Are there any software packages implementing this kind of stuff?

Comment: I used [GLPK](http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk) once and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: GAMS and LINGO are quite popular for linear, quadratic and nonlinear programming (integer programming supported too). MATLAB has a few built-in functions for linear programming, but for integer programming you would either have to write your own branch-and-bound code or pay for some toolbox. QPC (http://sigpromu.org/quadprog/) is a quadratic prog. solver with interface for MATLAB and it is rather efficient. You should definitely check YALMIP (http://goo.gl/Hzqq9) for MATLAB. CPLEX is free for academic use. There's also Gurobi (http://www.gurobi.com) and a lot more...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A few Linear Programming solvers:

- [GLPK](http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) (GNU Linear Programming Kit) is written in C. Take a look at [this intro](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-glpk1/). GLPK can also do Integer Programming, I believe.
- [CVXOPT](http://abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/) is a Python library for convex optimization. In addition to LP, it allows you to solve quadratic and semidefinite programs, as well.
- [Gurobi](http://www.gurobi.com): you can download a free trial.

Answer (score 14):

- See: [**LiPS**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lipside/):
  Linear Program Solver (LiPS) is intended for solving linear 
  programming problems. Main features: easy to use graphical interface, sensitivity 
  analysis, goal and mixed integer programming solver. LiPS supports MPS and simple LP format (like *lpsolve*).
- See also: [**CLP**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COIN-OR_CLP#CLP) 
  CLP stands for [COIN-OR](http://branchandcut.org/) LP (Computational Infrastructure for Operations Research: Linear Programming). CLP is an open-source linear programming solver written in C++.
- Also from COIN-OR is [**SYMPHONY**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COIN-OR_CLP#SYMPHONY), a program for solving integer programming (IP) problems and its variants.
- And: [**LpSolvers**](http://home.ubalt.edu/ntsbarsh/Research/LpSolvers.htm):

  This site provides installation information for a free-of-charge software package that solves Linear Program models by the Simplex Method and/or the Push-and-Pull Method.
- Finally, see the [**Linear and Integer Programming Software**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Solvers_and_scripting_.28programming.29_languages) section of Wikipedia for a more extensive list (with links) of both *free* and commercial linear programming solvers.

Comment: a nice list indeed! +1

Answer (score 5):

The Konrad-Zuse Institute in Berlin (ZIB), Germany provides a nice [suite](http://scip.zib.de/) to solve all kinds of LP / ILP tasks. It includes:

- **zimpl**: a language to model mathematical programms
- **SCIP**:  a mixed integer programming solver and constraint programming framework
- **SoPlex**:   a linear programming solver
- and more

Best of all, it is free! And all implementations are reasonably fast.

The state of the art in the commercial sector is probably IBM's [CPLEX Studio](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/optimization/cplex-optimization-studio/). This is an expansive piece of software, but IBM has an [academic program](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/websphere/products/optimization/academic-initiative/) where you get free licenses. However it is a bit of a pain to apply. I used to work with the CPLEX package because it includes this nice modelling language **ampl**. However when the equivalent free **zimpl** came out, I switched to the more available ZIB package.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/).
It' an excellent Python-based free alternative to Magma, Maple, Mathematica or Matlab!

Formulating LP problems using it it's also quite simple compared to other tools!

Comment: Yes actually sage uses (by default) GLPTK and can be tweaked to run gurobi as well.

Answer (score 2):

I use [lpsolve IDE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve/), in addition to using lpsolve [with R](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/R.htm), [with Python](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/Python.htm), etc.

Here is a list of some of the IDE features:

- Everything is graphical and mouse controlled
- Enter your lp model in all supported formats and even via an XLI
  (external language interface)
- Convert your lp model from any supported format to another supported
  format and even via an XLI
- Very user friendly editor to enter/change the model with syntax
  highlight
- Syntax checking of the model
- Solve the model
- See the results in grids
- Control every possible lpsolve option (tolerances, presolve, scaling,
  ...)
- View the matrix in grids
- Export model to HTML, RTF, LaTeX output
- Export matrix to CSV, HTML, RTF output
- Export results to CSV, HTML, RTF output
- Show statistics about the model.
- ...

More details: http://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve/