# Is there any mixed integer linear programming module capable of handling integer variables exactly?

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I have a mixed integer linear programming (MILP) problem with binary variables. I tried to treat binary variables as constrained real variables, but I could not provide a good solution to my problem. Are there any softwares which are able to give integer values to integer variables? Could you please recommend me some good modules?

Comment: No, MILP problems are typically solved by constraining real variables. Perhaps you did not model your problem correctly? can you show us your model?

Comment: My model is formulated in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2629509/how-is-it-worth-solving-the-constrained-minimization-problem-below.

Comment: A serious problem in my model is that the sigma values run from 0.01 to 100,000; thus, false values are sometimes obtained for the binary parameters.

Comment: Have you any idea what is wrong in my model?

Comment: In MIP solvers binary variables are allowed to be slightly non-integral (there is something called a integer feasibility tolerance). You can tighten this a little bit.  Otherwise have a look a indicator constraints. They sometimes behave better in case there are large coefficients. Of course the first thing is to look at the model formulation and see if that can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

If you define variables as binary or integer and let MILP solvers (e.g., CBC/CPLEX/Gurobi) solve your model, the solution will have those variables as binary or integer. It cannot be any other way - these are hard constraints.

On the other hand, if your model specifies these variables as constrained real variables, then you have to set up the objective, and possibly other constraints in such a way that these variables still turn out to be binary/integer. Otherwise, they will just show up as real numbers in the solution. There are ways to do this, and is considered the crux of modeling optimization problem, and can only be done in certain situations.

Leaving this aside, [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252654/good-software-for-linear-integer-programming?rq=1) might help you get a list of solvers where your binary/integer constraints are honored.